# Spectrum on first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm stuck in this exercise from Mathematical Logic, Ebbinghaus and would appreciate some help.

A set M of natural numbers is called a spectrum if there is a symbol set S and an S-sentence $\phi$ such that

M= {$n\in \mathbb{N} $|  $\phi$ has a model cointaining exactly n elements}.

Show:

(a) Every finite subset of {1,2,3...} is a spectrum.
(b) For every $m \geq 1$, the set of numbers $ > 0$ which are divisible by m is a spectrum.

I believe that some sentence with equality only would suit for part (a). However, I'm having some trouble to formalize an answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) : your idea is correct, equality suffices to do the trick. Can you find a sentence $\phi_m$ written with equality such that $M\models \phi$ if and only if $M$ has $m$ elements ?

Having done that, if $D$ is such a finite subset, what can you say about the sentence $\displaystyle\bigvee_{m\in D}\phi_m$?

(b) Fix $m$. Can you write a sentence in a language with only $R$ that states that $R$ is an equivalence relation such that each equivalence class has exactly $m$ elements? Can you see how that helps ?

Comment: Oh, I see it now. It's the $\displaystyle\bigvee_{m\in D}\phi_m$ part that was missing. Thank you very much, Max!